# C Segmentation Fault using Strcmp

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

im writing a program that checks to see if different types of brackets match or not in C, i'm new to C so i understand that a segmentation fault is related to memory but unsure what how to solve my issue?

the expected output would be someone would input the test_string such as and that would be a success while doing would print fail.
Thankyou

Comment: `strcmp` takes two strings. Two characters can be compared normally.

Comment: I helps one if you a) read the manual pages b) Turn on all the warnings for the compiler e.g. gcc -Wall c) Take heed of those warnings

Comment: Note: `while (x < (int)(strlen(test_string)-1)){` is suboptimal (and ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was very likely identified by your compiler's warnings: you should see a lot of them, telling you that you are passing a `char` to a function expecting a `char*`.

The `strcmp` function expects C strings, not simply `char*`, meaning that there should be a null terminator after the last character of the string. That's why you'd get a failure even if you passed a pointer to an individual character.

If you would like to compare individual characters, all you need is a plain `==`:

```
if(test_string[x] != '[')
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues that i see are

1) You are using strcmp but comparing a string with char.

2) Your brackets array is 20 char wide. If you ever go beyond 20 consecutive opening brackets, it would lead to seg fault.

3) When handling closing brackets, you are simply matching with previous index (i-1). Now following sequence will create an issue
    []]]
   Here after first two brackets your i become 0 and after that you will try to access brackets[-1] which is Array out of bound issue and can lead to seg fault.